# Why does the "g" modifier give different results when test() is called twice?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this code:

```
var reg = /a/g;
console.log(reg.test("a"));
console.log(reg.test("a"));
```

I get this result:

```
true
false
```

I have no idea how this could happen. I have tested in both Node.js (v8) and Firefox browser.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To workaround the problem, you can remove the `g` flag or reset `lastIndex` as in

```
var reg = /a/g;
console.log(reg.test("a"));
reg.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(reg.test("a"));
```

The problem arises because `test` is based around `exec` which looks for more matches after the first if passed the same string and the `g` flag is present.

> [**15.10.6.3**](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.6.3) `RegExp.prototype.test(string)` # Ⓣ Ⓡ
>
> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *match* be the result of evaluating the `RegExp.prototype.exec` (15.10.6.2) algorithm upon this `RegExp` object using *string* as the argument.
> 2. If *match* is not `null`, then return `true`; else return `false`.

The key part of `exec` is step 6 of [15.10.6.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.6.2):

> 6. Let global be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of R with argument "global".
> 7. If global is false, then let i = 0.

When `i` is not reset to 0, then `exec` (and therefore `test`) does not start looking at the beginning of the string.

This is useful for `exec` because you can loop to handle each match:

```
 var myRegex = /o/g;
 var myString = "fooo";
 for (var match; match = myRegex.exec(myString);) {
   alert(match + " at " + myRegex.lastIndex);
 }
```

but obviously it isn't so useful for `test`.

Comment: Which means I should set lastIndex to 0 myself,right?

Comment: +1 good explanation,I didn't knew that.

Comment: @NStal, Yes, setting `lastIndex` to 0 before testing will workaround the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a test is chosen to check if some pattern matches at all, but the global flag lets you loop through a string to either count the matches or,like exec, do something with each lastIndex. Another use is to set the lastIndex of the rx yourself before the test is peformed, to ignore matches before some character index.

```
var count=0, rx=/\s+/g, rx.lastIndex=100;
while(rx.test(string))count++;
```