# Javascript wildcard regex search gives inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making an interface for searching a fairly limited dictionary of words (2700 or so entries). The words are stored in an XML file thus:

```
<root>
    <w>aunt</w>
    <w>active volcano</w>
    <w>Xamoschi</w>
</root>
```

It is fairly basic - the user enters a string, and any matches are spit back out. The problem came when I wanted to include a wildcard character. If a user enters a string with asterisks, each asterisk is replaced by a regex to match zero or more characters, which can be anything.

So, when the user hits search, the script cycles through the XML tags and matches each `nodeValue` against the pattern `srch`:

```
var wildcardified = userinput.replace(/\*/g, ".*?");
var srch = new RegExp(wildcardified, "gi");

//for loop cycles through the xml, and tests with this:
if (srch.test(tag[i].firstChild.nodeValue) {
    //it's a match!
}
```

For the most part, it works as I'd hoped. But I'm getting some inconsistent results that I can't explain. For the values in the XML tags above, this is what happens with various inputs:

1. `a*` matches all three
2. `a*n` matches **aunt** and **active volcano**
3. `a*t` only matches **aunt**
4. `a*ti` only matches **active volcano**

Should #3 not also match the **act** in **active volcano**?

I see the same kind of results with other similar sets of words. I've tried to isolate the specific issue, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

The Question: **Can someone explain why #3 is not returning "active volcano", and what I can do to fix such behaviour?**

Incidentally, I want it to be non-greedy, but just in case that was the issue, I tested both with and without the `?`. Both returned the same inconsistent results above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `g` modifier in `new RegExp(wildcardified, "gi");` that is causing you trouble.  For an explanation and a workaround see [Why does the "g" modifier give different results when test() is called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911542/why-does-the-g-modifier-give-different-results-when-test-is-called-twice/8911576#8911576)

Comment: Fantastic!!! Setting `srch.lastIndex = 0` after the `if` statement solved the problem instantly.

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh, yeah.  That property of `test` is probably a spec error, but it's not going away anytime soon.

Comment: Either way it's interesting to know. The fact that it's weird makes it memorable, so hopefully it won't trip me up again. Anyway, there is no way I would ever have figured out what the problem was on my own, so thank you kindly! Saved me a headache and a half.