# Value.replace in javascript for not allowing specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using a regular expression in javascript that allows only numbers and two kinds of separators "," or "." This regular expression is the following:

```
/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/g
```

Now, it's mandatory that if a user tries to enter a character or something else besides a number with , or . separator to prevent him. To be more specific if a user types `123asv` I should display only the 123.

So i wrote this:

```
value.replace(/[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/g, '');
```

But this is not allowing enter number. This is reasonable because i replace every value that matches the above regex with space. How to edit it so as to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: Is `1,sf4` an expected input with `1,4` as expected output? Can letters or just any non-digit symbols appear anywhere?

Comment: Yes, the output should be 13,4 or 13.4 or 13. Every other character should be prevented

Comment: Try to use `value = value.replace(/[^\d,.]+|[.,](?=.*[,.])/g, '')`, and then `value.test(/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/)`.

Comment: That's fine but i see a weird behaviour. I have a function to preventr more than three decimal poin {
  let decimalIndex;
  if (e.target.value.includes('.')) {
    decimalIndex = e.target.value.indexOf('.');
  } else {
    decimalIndex = e.target.value.indexOf(',');
  }
  console.log(decimalIndex);
  if (decimalIndex > -1) {
    const decimals =
      e.target.value.substring(decimalIndex, e.target.value.length);
    if (decimals.length > 3 && e.keyCode !== 8) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}; By applying the value.replace with the above regex the onKeyDown is not applied

Comment: If you do not care about the commas and periods, just use `value = value.replace(/[^\d,.]+/g, '')`

Comment: Make it an aswer :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current scenario, you need to remove any digits, `,` and `.` symbols from the input string, since you have extra code that validate/sanitizes extra comma/periods:

```
value = value.replace(/[^\d,.]+/g, '')
```

The `[^\d,.]+` pattern matches 1 or more chars that are not digits, `.` and `,`, and `g` modifier matches multiple occurrences. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2xMR9/2).

Note that in case there is no additional code to validate separators, you may add an alternative to remove all `.` and `,` but their last occurrences:

```
value = value.replace(/[^\d,.]+|[.,](?=.*[,.])/g, '')
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2xMR9/1). The `[.,](?=.*[,.])` matches a `,` or `.` that are followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars and then another `,` or `.`, but only the first matched `.` or `,` are removed since the `(?=...)` lookahead is a non-consuming construct.

Then test if the value matches the number pattern:

```
if (value.test(/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/)) { ... }
```

[Do not use the global modifier with the `RegExp#test()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911542/why-does-the-g-modifier-give-different-results-when-test-is-called-twice).